# Will galactic filament indefinitely expand while its galaxy clusters indefinitely disperse?

Tags: dark-matter, galaxy-cluster, gravitational-lensing

Exciting discoveries of weak gravitational lensing suggest the [existence of galactic filaments made of dark matter that are the size of galactic superclusters](https://doi.org/10.1093/mnras/stx517). My questions involves the future of the galactic filaments while space indefinitely expands between the galaxy clusters within each galactic filament. Will the filaments indefinitely expand with the indefinite expansion of space or will the filaments divide because of an event horizon? For example, event horizon paradigms suggest that the expansion of space will eventually isolate each galaxy cluster from each other galaxy cluster. Perhaps we do not yet have enough information to calculate this because we know little about dark matter.

I also posted this question at the [moderated news group sci.astro.research](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sci.astro.research/l5-hGFMaVCU/discussion). A moderator noted: "I think your last statement is *definitely* true: we don't know enough about dark matter to calculate this."

Comment: I also posted this question at the moderated news group sci.astro.research (https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sci.astro.research/l5-hGFMaVCU/discussion). A moderator noted: "I think your last statement is *definitely* true: we don't know enough about dark matter to calculate this."

Comment: if the universe continue to have the accelerated expansion it does now, eventually atoms will no longer be able to form because of space expanding between elementary particles, so galaxies would not be able to form